# What is the best way to transform object names to a desired format

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Whats the best way to map all object properties into a new object format with different property names example:

**this is the desired format**

```
const person = {
  firstName: 'john',
  lastName: 'doe',
  houses: [{ housName: 'Kruger' }]
}
```

**and I have these two objects**

```
const person1 = {
  prenom: 'john', //this should be mapped to the firstName
  nom: 'doe', //this should be mapped to the lastName
  houses: [{ house_name: 'Kruger' }]
}
```

```
const person2 = {
  name: 'john', // this should be mapped to the firstName
  familyName: 'doe', // this should be assigned to the lastName
  Houses: [{ House_Name: 'Kruger' }]
};
```

The goals is to make person1 and person2 with all their properties and sub properties look like person.

**I HAVE TRIED**

```
export class Person {
  @Expose({ name: 'prenom' })
  firstName: string;

  @Expose({ name: 'nom' })
  lastName: string;

  }
}

//this should give a formatted version from person1 ==> person
const formatted = plainToClass(person1,Person)
```

However this would require me to create multiple iterations of Person class which is not convenient if we would like to use this class for typing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please may you share that effort as a [mcve]?

Comment: I find the inconsistent spellings: `houses`, `Houses`, `housName`, `house_name`, `House_Name` very distracting.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get all the `object` keys and values by `Object.entries(obj)`, then on each key we need to turn it from `pascal case` to `camel case` first we need to turn the string to `lower case` then with `replace` `/_([a-z])/gi` which capture the first letter after the underscore `_`, and turn it `Upper case`.

```
str.toLowerCase().replace(/_([a-z])/gi, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
```

Then reduce the array and covert it back to an object.

```
const mapToCamelCase = (obj) => {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => {
        var keyCamelCased = toCamelCase(key)
       acc[keyCamelCased] = value
       return acc
    }, {})
}
```

```js
const person1 = {
  first_name: 'john',
  last_name: 'doe',
  houses: [{ house_name: 'Kruger' }]
}
const person2 = {
  First_Name: 'john',
  Last_Name: 'doe',
  Houses: [{ House_Name: 'Kruger' }]
};


const toCamelCase = (str) => {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/_([a-z])/gi, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
}


const mapToCamelCase = (obj) => {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => {
        var keyCamelCased = toCamelCase(key)
       acc[keyCamelCased] = value
       return acc
    }, {})
}

console.log(mapToCamelCase(person1))
console.log(mapToCamelCase(person2))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive function can do the name conversion you want. This will work for input with any depth of entries in it.

Using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const person1 = { first_name: "john", last_name: "doe", houses: [{ house_name: "Kruger" }], }; const person2 = { First_Name: "john", Last_Name: "doe", Houses: [{ House_Name: "Kruger" }], }; const person3 = { first_name: "john", last_name: "doe", houses: [ { house_name: "Kruger", phone_numbers: [{ ext_code: "+54", phone_number: 232242323 }], }, ], };

const formatName = (str) => {
  return str
    .split("_")
    .map(
      (w, index) =>
        (index > 0 ? w[0].toUpperCase() : w[0].toLowerCase()) + w.substring(1)
    )
    .join("");
};

const formatNames = (input) => {
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input.map((item) => formatNames(item));
  } else if (typeof input === "object") {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => [
        formatName(key),
        formatNames(value),
      ])
    );
  }
  return input;
};

console.log(formatNames(person1));
console.log(formatNames(person2));
console.log(formatNames(person3));
```

Note: If you made `formatName` function an argument to `formatNames` then `formatNames` is much more flexible as it can be used to form differently name-formatted objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think my description was a bit confusing, however I changed the description to be more clear, your reply is correct however It focuses on formatting names rather than mapping to different properties

Answer (score 0):

My workaround will be creating a class file something like this

in person.js

```
class Person {
  constructor(personObj) {
    this.firstName = personObj.first_name,
    this.lastName = personObj.Last_Name,
    this.houses = personObj.Houses;
  }
}

const person1 = {
  first_name: 'john',
  last_name: 'doe',
  houses: [{ house_name: 'Kruger' }]
}

const formatted = new Person(person1)
```